# Set Auto Complete Text View Text Alignment to be right aligned

Tags: android

I am trying to set the Text alignment of an auto complete text view to be right aligned, I used the android:gravity="Right", on the emulator It is working find, but on the device it is always left aligned,

Does any one have an idea?
note: I am using Samsung Galaxy Tab as a test device,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using [setGravity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29) method. Maybe it will affect and on galaxy too.

Comment: It seems to be galaxy-specific issue. On my htc desire all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set *textAlignment* attribute to *right* in autocompleteTextView. Surely will help.